# What are the months of Jewish civil and religious calendar?

Tags: calendar, christianity

I understand that Jewish religion has two calendars; one is Civil for Kings, childbirth, contracts etc. and second for festivals.

what are the months of these calendars and how they are related datewise with current Christian  calendar?

Comment: There are different moments for the computing of the beginning of the year and for reckoning years (as in X years of a ruler's kingship or the celebration of the new year for the trees) but the months are the same for both. http://www.jewfaq.org/calendar.htm

Comment: I read somewhere that months are same. So what are the months and their co-relation with Christian calendar?

Comment: check out the link I posted for a discussion and a list (including approximate correlations -- as a secular calendar is solar and the Jewish one is an adjusted lunar, there is a general correlation but not a strict one.

Comment: Where did you learn that there are these two separate calendars?

Comment: @Danno, That qualifies as an answer.

Comment: @Yitzchak though this is not the place to have this conversation, to my mind this qualifies as a downvote worthy request which doesn't reflect the basic research expected of a good question. So I won't give the simple google search as an answer.

Comment: @Yitzchak http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1975

Comment: @msh210, I think [tag:christianity] is misapplied, as the calendar in question is the one used conventionally throughout the secular world. If the question was really about a religious calendar that's an alternative to our religious calendar, then this question would probably be "Off-topic: comparative religions."

Comment: @IsaacMoses, as you know, you can edit every bit as well as I can. In this case, I tagged it that way since the calendar, though common among atheists etc., is Christian in origin, and I think the question is on-topic because the calendar is common among atheists etc. Feel free to detag if you disagree; and certainly you should feel free to, user426.

Comment: The common calendar is pagan Roman in origin, in particular its months, with a minor 16th century CE technical adjustment because it was slowly drifting against the seasons.  The fact that Gregory XIII tried to use religious authority to achieve the minor change probably delayed its general acceptance, for example until the 20th century in Russia.

Answer (score 1):

To quote Rosends (who I assume is Danno):

"There are different moments for the computing of the beginning of the year and for reckoning years (as in X years of a ruler's kingship or the celebration of the new year for the trees) but the months are the same for both."
"Check out the link I posted for a discussion and a list (including approximate correlations -- as a secular calendar is solar and the Jewish one is an adjusted lunar, there is a general correlation but not a strict one."

Source: http://www.jewfaq.org/calendar.htm

Comment: rosends was once upon a time known as Danno. :)